# C++ scoped lock in loop blocks another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex lock_m;

void childTh() {
    while(true) {
        //std::this_thread::yield();
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockChild(lock_m);

        std::cout << "childTh CPN1" << std::endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main(int, char**) {
    std::thread thr(childTh);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockMain(lock_m);

    std::cout << "MainTh CPN1" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
    return 0;
}
```

Main thread blocks on lockMain and never reach "MainTh CPN1". I expect that main thread should acquire lock_m when childTh reach end of iteration because lockChild is destroyed and lock_m is released. But this never happens.
Can you please describe in details why main thread don't have time to acquire the lock before childTh lock it again ?
With sleep_for main can reach "MainTh CPN1", but with yield not.
I know that condition_variable can be used to notify and unblock another thread, but is it possible to use just scoped lock ? So it looks that it is risky to use scoped lock in different threads, even if it the same lock.

Answer (score 1):

In `childTh`, `lockChild` doesn't release the mutex until the iteration ends.  Right after that iteration ends, it starts the next one.  This means you only have the time between the destruction of `lockChild` and then the initialization of `lockChild` in the next iteration.  Since that happens as basically the next instruction, there basically isn't any time for `lockMain` to acquire a lock on the mutex.  To save CPU cycles a typical lock acquire is going to yield for a short duration, which is not as short as single instruction, so there is basically no chance of `lockMain` being able to lock the mutex as it would have to be timed perfectly.  If you change `childTh` to

```
void childTh() {
    while(true) {
        //std::this_thread::yield();
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockChild(lock_m);

            std::cout << "childTh CPN1" << std::endl;
        }

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
```

now you have a 1 second delay between when the mutex is release by `lockChild` and when it reacquired in the next iteration, which then allows `lockMain` to acquire the mutex.

---

Also note that you are not calling `join` on `thr` at the end of main.  Not doing so causes `thr`'s destructor to throw an exception which will cause your program to terminate imporperly.

Comment: this is just example code there is no proper program completion and so on. This is example about lock conflicts.
Adding sleep always is hack. Is there a proper way to take time to acquire mutex from another thread ? In real projects scoped locks widely used, but in special cases it could lead to the described problem.

Comment: @Yuri That most likely means you are holding onto the lock for too long.  A lock should only be held for the smallest amount of time possible, which helps to minimize this type of scenario.  If this still happens, you might want to consider using a different synchronization method like a atomic variable or condition variable.

Comment: IMO, this would be a good opportunity to introduce the OP to the word "starvation." Your answer explains how the `childTh()` thread in this example _starves_ the main thread.